# ColdFusion code calling a .NET web service

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a .NET web service to be consumed by our integration partner's ColdFusion code.

Partner is making SOAP requests &  receiving SOAP responses, but they are saying they need a plain XML response. I am not sure whether this would be a ColdFusion query or .NET query.

My question: Is this something configurable on our end or their end?

If it is on .NET, is there a way we can instruct to return specific formats as responses, say in this case, plain XML.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to consume a .NET web service from a partner in ColdFusion and I was able to pass along this tidbit from CF documentation. Everything worked flawlessly.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78b4.html

> To consume a web service that is implemented in a technology other than ColdFusion, the web
>   service must have one of the following sets of options:
>
> - rpc as the SOAP binding style and encoding as the encodingStyle
> - document as the SOAP binding style and literal as the encodingStyle